# Project folder in Visual Studio - Read only and cannot be written to

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I'm currently trying to make an admin page in an e-commerce website using windows 8 and Visual Studio 2015 Community that should allow an Admin to update/change items on the site.

When I attempt to edit an item on the site I get the following error:

> "Access to the path 'C:\Users..(Web site path)..\Secure' is denied."

The following description is given with the error:

> "ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access."

Stack trace for the Error:

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\..(Web Site Path)..\Secure' is denied.]
    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +419
    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +886
    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +144
    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +91
    System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +100
    Secure_Admin.btnImgUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +149
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +138
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6023
```

I have checked the security section in the project folder and I have complete access to all files in the web site. However, the check box for "Read Only" is checked and when I uncheck it and click "Apply" and then "OK", the box re-checks itself when I open the properties window.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Tried running VS as administrator? Try that and restarting your pc

Comment: As far as I know, I am running it as an administrator. In case I'm not, is there a way to check?

Comment: If VS is running as user, the title bar reads "Microsoft Visual Studio", if it runs as admin, it reads "Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)"

Comment: Ah, well it seems it doesn't have the (Administrator) after the title. I thought my main (and only) account on my laptop had admin privileges by default. Can I edit my main account to have admin controls?

Comment: You do have admin privileges, but Visual Studio is smart enough to know that it doesn't need admin by default. Just right-click on the shortcut and click run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath 99% that OP tries to write *file* to *folder path* which will always fail. Nothing will help till OP realize that.

Comment: Perhaps you could help then? What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder, select PROPERTIES >> SECURITY and give your all users full privileges on the folder. You will need to be logged in as an admin user.

Comment: All users full privileges? Very security-oriented. This is not required and he already has full access on his user, read the question.

Comment: I have done this. All users have full privileges in the folder and its made no difference. Like I said, the problem seems to be that I'm unable to uncheck the "Read Only" box, which resets after I close the properties window, even though I click "Apply" and then "OK".